# How to send manual payload in jQuery Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I was working on jQuery data table without server-side caching and pagination earlier, but now I am getting API that is performing server-side pagination searching and sorting.

I have some idea about server-side functionality provided by data table but my question is how can
I pass my own parameters to ajax request, I have noticed that jQuery Datatable sends a payload that contains many things but I need to send some extra information as well to the backend.

My Code-

```
 $('#dataTable').ready(function () {
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
    "url": "API/GetDetails",
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "GET",
    "beforeSend": function(xhr){
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
    "Bearer Token");
   }
  }
});
```

})

Is there any way to change the payload values sent to the backend while making Api request?
If yes how and where I should need to edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can send custom http variables as per their documentation

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.myKey = "myValue";
            // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
            // etc
        }
    }
} );
```

} );

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how to show pagination currently datatable is not creating pagination for me, I think datatable needs response "draw", "recordsTotal", "recordsFiltered". but for me backend response key is different is there any way to configure this?

Comment: @RikkMor - if you have a new question, you should ask it as a new question, rather than adding it as a comment. That way, you can also show what you mean by "backend response key is different". However, this type of question has been asked before on Stack Overflow, so you may be able to answer your own question with some research. If you cannot alter the server-side response on the server itself, take a look at the [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option.